# Python: create a sub dictionary swapping the keys

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I have a Python dictionary with contains lists such as the following:

```
my_dict = {
           'list1':[10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
           'list2':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
           'list3':[10, 100, 200]
          }
```

I want to create another dictionary, whose keys are the same as the first dictionary, but the values are stored under another key of the dictionary, such as the following:

```
my_desired_dict = {
                   'list1':{'my_key':[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]},
                   'list2':{'my_key':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]},
                   'list3':{'my_key':[10, 100, 200]}
                  }
```

The key name for the inner dictionary will be the same (my_key) for all. How can I achieve this, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve that with a simple dict comprehension

```
new_key = "aKey"
my_dict = {k: {new_key: v} for k, v in my_dict.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_desired_dict = {k: {'my_key': v} for k, v in my_dict.items()}
```